# Zip Lists together based on many to one relationship

Tags: python

I have two lists and I would like to find a way to link them together (I'm not sure the exact term for doing this) by zipping them.

In list one I have a series of tif files:

```
    list1=['LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band1.tif',
    ,'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band2.tif'  
    'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band3.tif','LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band1.tif',
    'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band2.tif',
    'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band3.tif']
```

in list two I have two files:

```
list2=[LT50300281984137PAC00_mask.tif,LT50300281994260XXX03_mask.tif]
```

I want to zip the files in list one which start with `LT50300281984137PAC00` to the file in list 2 which starts the same way, and the same for the files which start with `LT50300281994260XXX03`

The code I have tried is:

`ziplist=zip(sorted(list1),sorted(list2)`

but this returns:

```
[('LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band1', 'LT50300281984137PAC00_mask.tif'), ('LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band2', 'LT50300281994260XXX03_mask.tif')]
```

I would like this to be returned:

```
 [('LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band1',LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band2,LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band3, 'LT50300281984137PAC00_mask.tif'), ('LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band1.tif', 'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band2.tif','LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band3.tif','LT50300281994260XXX03_mask.tif')]
```

Comment: These filenames look familiar.. :P

Comment: Are you sure that's the output you want? It just seems like there would probably be better formats for whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: The tool I have been using is actually `arcpy.ListRasters()` instead of just lists.  The mask in list two is a cloud mask I am applying to each band of the corresponding files in list 1, so that is ultimately what I am after.  I just don't know how to apply the 1 same mask to multiple different files and then have python recognize that the files have changed and therefore a new mask is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

list1 = [
    'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band1.tif',
    'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band2.tif',
    'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band3.tif',
    'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band1.tif',
    'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band2.tif',
    'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band3.tif'
]

list2 = [
    'LT50300281984137PAC00_mask.tif',
    'LT50300281994260XXX03_mask.tif'
]

def extract_key(s):
    return s[:s.index('_')]

l = sorted(list1 + list2, key=extract_key)
l = [tuple(items) for s, items in groupby(l, key=extract_key)]
```

Result:

```
[('LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band1.tif', 'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band2.tif', 'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band3.tif', 'LT50300281984137PAC00_mask.tif'), ('LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band1.tif', 'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band2.tif', 'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band3.tif', 'LT50300281994260XXX03_mask.tif')]
```

The idea is to sort the union of the two lists by the first part of each filename (`extract_key`). Then use `groupby` to create groups of the same first part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions and builtin function `filter`

```
In [24]: [tuple(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(e.split('_')[0]), list1)+[e]) for e in list2]
Out[24]:
[('LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band1.tif',
  'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band2.tif',
  'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band3.tif',
  'LT50300281984137PAC00_mask.tif'),
 ('LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band1.tif',
  'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band2.tif',
  'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band3.tif',
  'LT50300281994260XXX03_mask.tif')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done using regex.

```
import re
list1=['LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band1.tif'
       ,'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band2.tif',  
       'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band3.tif','LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band1.tif',
       'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band2.tif',
       'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band3.tif']

list2=['LT50300281984137PAC00_mask.tif','LT50300281994260XXX03_mask.tif']

match = re.findall(r'(\b\w+(?:PAC00)\w+.\w+\b)'," ".join(list1))
tuple1 =  tuple(match+[list2[0]])


match = re.findall(r'(\b\w+(?:0XXX0)\w+.\w+\b)'," ".join(list1))
tuple2 =  tuple(match+[list2[1]])

print [tuple1,tuple2]
```

Output

```
[('LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band1.tif', 'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band2.tif', 'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band3.tif', 'LT50300281984137PAC00_mask.tif'), ('LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band1.tif', 'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band2.tif', 'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band3.tif', 'LT50300281994260XXX03_mask.tif')]
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary will work better here, you can then later repurpose it for what you need:

```
results = {}

for f in list2:
    common = f.split('_')[0]
    results[common] = []

for f in list1:
    common = f.split('_')[0]
    try:
        results[common].append(f)
    except KeyError:
        print('{} not a valid grouper'.format(common))

# To convert into a list of tuples
as_list = [(k,)+tuple(v) for k,v in results.iteritems()]
print(as_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `itertools.chain` and `itertools.groupby` , with a lambda expression to take only till the first `_` for the grouping. Example -

```
>>> from itertools import chain,groupby
>>> list1=['LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band1.tif','LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band2.tif','LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band3.tif','LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band1.tif','LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band2.tif','LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band3.tif']
>>> list2=['LT50300281984137PAC00_mask.tif','LT50300281994260XXX03_mask.tif']
>>>
>>> chained_sorted = sorted(chain(list1,list2))
>>> ret = []
>>> for i, x in groupby(chained_sorted,lambda x: x.split('_')[0]):
...     ret.append(tuple(x))
...
>>> ret
[('LT50300281984137PAC00_mask.tif', 'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band1.tif', 'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band2.tif', 'LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band3.tif'), ('LT50300281994260XXX03_mask.tif', 'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band1.tif', 'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band2.tif', 'LT50300281994260XXX03_sr_band3.tif')]
```

Answer (score 0):

My first answer on StackOverflow, so please be patient.  But I didn't see a need for zip()

```
mask1, mask2 = list2[0], list2[1]
for b in reversed(list1):
    if b[0:20] in mask1:
        mask1 = b + " " + mask1
    else:
        mask2 = b + " " + mask2

ziplist = [tuple(mask1.split()), tuple(mask2.split())]
```

I think ziplist should now be what you were asking for.